# TikZ plots are not centered

Tags: tikz-styles

I use the following to show examples of overfitting, underfitting and balance:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, decorations.text, calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x)=0.5*pow(abs(\x-2),2)-0.06*pow(\x-2,3);}]
 \foreach \Z in {1,...,42}
 {\pgfmathsetmacro{\X}{\Z/10}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\Y}{f(\X)+0.9*rnd}
 \ifnum\Z=1
  \xdef\LstOne{(\X,\Y)}
  \xdef\LstTwo{"(\X,\Y)"}
 \else
  \xdef\LstOne{\LstOne (\X,\Y)}
  \xdef\LstTwo{\LstTwo,"(\X,\Y)"}
 \fi}
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=over,xshift=-10cm]
 \foreach \Z in {1,...,40}
 {\pgfmathsetmacro{\Last}{{\LstTwo}[\Z-1]}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\Current}{{\LstTwo}[\Z]}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\Next}{{\LstTwo}[\Z+1]}
  \edef\temp{\noexpand\path ($0.6*\Current+0.2*\Last+0.2*\Next$)   coordinate   (p\Z);}
  \temp
  \ifnum\Z=1
  \xdef\LstThree{(p\Z)}
  \else
  \xdef\LstThree{\LstThree (p\Z)}
  \fi}
 \foreach \Z in {1,...,42}
 {\pgfmathsetmacro{\Coor}{{\LstTwo}[\Z-1]}
 \fill \Coor circle[radius=1pt];}
 \draw[thick,blue] plot[smooth] coordinates \LstThree;
 \end{scope}
 %
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=under,xshift=-15cm]
 \foreach \Z in {1,...,42}
 {\pgfmathsetmacro{\Coor}{{\LstTwo}[\Z-1]}
 \fill \Coor circle[radius=1pt];}
 \draw[thick,blue] (0.1,0.4) -- (4.2,2);
 \end{scope}
 %
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=good,xshift=-5cm]
 \foreach \Z in {1,...,42}
 {\pgfmathsetmacro{\Coor}{{\LstTwo}[\Z-1]}
 \fill \Coor circle[radius=1pt];}
 \draw[thick,blue] plot[smooth,domain=0.1:4.2,variable=\x] (\x,{f(\x)+0.45});
 \end{scope}
 %
 \foreach \X in {over,good,under}
 {\draw[gray,thin] ([xshift=-3pt,yshift=3pt]\X.north west) rectangle  ([xshift=3pt,yshift=-3pt]\X.south east);
  \draw[stealth-stealth,thick] ([xshift=-3pt,yshift=3pt]\X.north west) node{} |- ([xshift=3pt,yshift=-3pt]\X.south east);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{minipage}{0.32\textwidth}\centering
\caption{Underfitting}\label{fig:underfitting}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.32\textwidth}\centering
\caption{Overfitting}\label{fig:overfitting}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.32\textwidth}\centering
\caption{Balance}\label{fig:balance}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

This results in the following plots:

[image]

How can I align the plots so they take up exactly 1/3 of the text width each and the caption is centred underneath them with a skip inbetween plot and caption?

Comment: The `tikzpicture` is too wide.

Comment: Is there a way to automatically scale it to 1/3 of the page width?

Comment: \resizebox  (adjustbox) and tikzscale (package).  More importantly, you are adding a space every time you end a line with } (at least outside tikzpicture).  Use \hfil instead.

Comment: Could you elaborate further on that? How should I use \resizebox, \tikzscale and \hfil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The individual scopes are not too big, but putting them all into one tikzpicture is not a good idea.  The common definitions can be made outside the tikzpicture environment (but inside the figure).

I did have to split up the loop generating the axes.  Local bounding boxes are not saved globally.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, decorations.text, calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
 \tikzset{declare function={f(\x)=(-0.06*(\x-2)+0.5)*(\x-2)*(\x-2);}}% applied math style
 \foreach \Z in {1,...,42} {\pgfmathsetmacro{\X}{\Z/10}%
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\Y}{f(\X)+0.9*rnd}%
 \ifnum\Z=1
  \xdef\LstOne{(\X,\Y)}%
  \xdef\LstTwo{"(\X,\Y)"}%
 \else
  \xdef\LstOne{\LstOne (\X,\Y)}%
  \xdef\LstTwo{\LstTwo,"(\X,\Y)"}%
 \fi}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.32\textwidth}\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=over]
 \foreach \Z in {1,...,40}
 {\pgfmathsetmacro{\Last}{{\LstTwo}[\Z-1]}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\Current}{{\LstTwo}[\Z]}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\Next}{{\LstTwo}[\Z+1]}
  \edef\temp{\noexpand\path ($0.6*\Current+0.2*\Last+0.2*\Next$)   coordinate   (p\Z);}
  \temp
  \ifnum\Z=1
  \xdef\LstThree{(p\Z)}
  \else
  \xdef\LstThree{\LstThree (p\Z)}
  \fi}
 \foreach \Z in {1,...,42}
 {\pgfmathsetmacro{\Coor}{{\LstTwo}[\Z-1]}
 \fill \Coor circle[radius=1pt];}
 \draw[thick,blue] plot[smooth] coordinates \LstThree;
 \end{scope}
 \draw[gray,thin] ([xshift=-3pt,yshift=3pt]over.north west) rectangle  ([xshift=3pt,yshift=-3pt]over.south east);
 \draw[stealth-stealth,thick] ([xshift=-3pt,yshift=3pt]over.north west) |- ([xshift=3pt,yshift=-3pt]over.south east);
 %\draw[red] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Overfitting}\label{fig:overfitting}
\end{minipage}\hfil
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.32\textwidth}\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=under]
 \foreach \Z in {1,...,42}
 {\pgfmathsetmacro{\Coor}{{\LstTwo}[\Z-1]}
 \fill \Coor circle[radius=1pt];}
 \draw[thick,blue] (0.1,0.4) -- (4.2,2);
 \end{scope}
 \draw[gray,thin] ([xshift=-3pt,yshift=3pt]under.north west) rectangle  ([xshift=3pt,yshift=-3pt]under.south east);
 \draw[stealth-stealth,thick] ([xshift=-3pt,yshift=3pt]under.north west) |- ([xshift=3pt,yshift=-3pt]under.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Underfitting}\label{fig:underfitting}
\end{minipage}\hfil
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.32\textwidth}\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=good]
 \foreach \Z in {1,...,42}
 {\pgfmathsetmacro{\Coor}{{\LstTwo}[\Z-1]}
 \fill \Coor circle[radius=1pt];}
 \draw[thick,blue] plot[smooth,domain=0.1:4.2,variable=\x] (\x,{f(\x)+0.45});
 \end{scope}
 \draw[gray,thin] ([xshift=-3pt,yshift=3pt]good.north west) rectangle  ([xshift=3pt,yshift=-3pt]good.south east);
 \draw[stealth-stealth,thick] ([xshift=-3pt,yshift=3pt]good.north west) |- ([xshift=3pt,yshift=-3pt]good.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Balance}\label{fig:balance}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm!